# Android Studio, Analyze Apk gives IDE Fatal error(Exception in Plugin Android Support) and i get Parsing error while installing on an android phone

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk, gradle-plugin

Gradle file code
[image: image1]

Plugins Settings Screenshot
[image: image2]

Error while analyzing apk
[image: image3]

Comment: It is unacceptable to post nothing but links. Describe the desired process, the expected input, the desired output, the problem you're having (including errors), and what you've tried. We should be able to see everything in your question post.

Comment: At first I did mention all those. but when i did that, I couldn't upload it because there was too much of code. And i cant upload images directly yet hence the links.